# How to customize delete button in UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I tried to customize my **delete** button in `UITableView`. I used a function but it didn't work because Xcode found an error. By the way I'm using custom cells in `UITableView`.

This is my code:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    @IBOutlet weak var myTableView: UITableView!


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
            let deleteButton = UITableViewRowAction(style: .Default, title: "Delete", handler: { (action, indexPath) in
                self.myTableView.dataSource?.tableView?(
                    self.myTableView,
                    commitEditingStyle: .Delete,
                    forRowAtIndexPath: indexPath
                )

                return
            })

            deleteButton.backgroundColor = UIColor.blackColor()

            return [deleteButton]
    }


}
```

And in this line is error:

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
```

the erros is: **Objective-C method 'tableView:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:' provided by method 'tableView(*:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:)' conflicts with optional requirement method 'tableView(*:editActionsForRowAtIndexPath:)' in protocol 'UITableViewDelegate'**

So I want to change the text and background color. If there is any other method, like using icon and not text please show me, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is indicating that the function you defined with the same method signature as the one defined in `UITableViewDelegate` has different types that are not compatible.  Specifically your return type needs to be `[UITableViewRowAction]?` instead of `[AnyObject]?`

Change:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]? {
```

To:

```
    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

Comment: Can I somehow use a PNG icon instead of "Delete" text ? I also mentioned this in question.

Comment: @Emi What you have should work, you just need to set the `backgroundColor` and `title` of the `UITableViewRowAction` that you create

Comment: Ya, this method works but I'm asking using **PNG icon** instead of **"Delete "text**.

Comment: I do not believe that is possible using the default functionality provided by `UITableView`.  You would probably have to implement that yourself.  Having said that, you can use unicode / emoji to put images in the text.

Answer (score 2):

Your main problem is that the UITableViewDelegate method is

```
optional public func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [UITableViewRowAction]?
```

and not

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editActionsForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> [AnyObject]?
```

I hope this helps you

Comment: Thanks, it works ! Just edit your answer to be more clear to other users. Do it as marked one.